# Google Cloud: How to move a running Kubernetes cluster to a shared VPC?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We have one Kubernetes cluster running and we want to connect it to a new cluster. I found Google Clouds [multicluster-service (MCS API)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-services) which seems promising, but it needs all [clusters to be in the same VPC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-services#requirements).

How do one migrate / move / add a running cluster to a VPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can not **move** the cluster to another VPC, although you can create a new or clone the cluster to new VPC.

You can clone the existing one by using **DUPLICATE** tab in cluster details however it will just create infrastructure with the same config specs, during that time you can update Networking (VPC) as per need.

Once the duplicate(cloned) cluster is up & running in the desired VPC, you can start migrating your workloads, like deployment, secrets, stateful sets etc.

For workload migration you can checkout the tool : https://velero.io/

**Velero** is mostly useful for creating the backup & restore option.

it would be easy to migrate the workloads instead of going by applying the old **YAML** method however it's more on your setup.

Here is my small article about the `migrating/cloning` workload across **GCP** **GKE** clusters: https://faun.pub/clone-migrate-data-between-kubernetes-clusters-with-velero-e298196ec3d8

Comment: Thank you! So "Workloads" are everything other than the stateless cluster? Also, pressing the duplicate button and changing network settings, will incoming traffic automatically be received on to the new cluster?

Comment: No you have to create ingress and all if you are using it like Nginx or GCe ingress, you can clone your your resources (pvc, pv, ingress using) velero and migrate